# Database object pattern for MVC in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, activerecord, express

#### tl:dr;

I want to provide the database object to my models and controllers in ExpressJS. How should I do this?

#### Longer explanation:

My background is in working with Codeigniter and the active-record implementation it has. I have seen other example Node implementations (the mean-stack for instance), however, I was looking to get a site something simple, low-level and that I understood from the ground-up.

The problems is that I don't know express well enough to understand how I should be passing objects around. So I have rounting, db connections and pages rendering all well. However, I am unsure about DB connections being provided to the actual controllers or models.

So, the setup I presently have is:

#### App.js:

```
...
//Start the database 
var Db = require('mysql-activerecord');
var db = new Db.Adapter({
server: 'localhost',
username: 'root',
password: '********',
database: 'test'
});
// }}}
...
require('./config/routes')(app);
```

And for config/routes.js

```
  2 /*
  3  Exporting variable:
  4  @param app The express App 
  5 */
  6 
  7 
  8 module.exports = function(app) {
  9 
 10     //Home route
 11     var index = require('../server/controllers/index');
 12     app.get('/', index.render);
 13 
 14 }
 15
```

#### So...

The question is perhaps more stylistic than technical. My questions are:

1. Am I thinking about this the right way?
2. How would you recommend going about connecting this? Should I use 'require(../..)' in the controllers or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the db object to your routes.js (or any other required file you make) file as well:

```
require('./config/routes')({ app: app, db: db });
```